# Finding inner text value from XML file

Tags: c#

When I write this code, I get only the parent tag value. I want to get their childnodes value also, please tell me about this.

```
XmlDocument DOC = new XmlDocument();
DOC.RemoveAll();
DOC.Load("C:\\Users\\DIGITEL EYE SYSTEM\\Desktop\\response.xml");

foreach (XmlNode AllNodes in ParentNode)
{
    Project.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
    if (AllNodes.ChildNodes == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("AppBuilderForms"))
    {
        //  Project.Forms = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("");
        // String sb = AllNodes["Forms"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (AllNodes.ChildNodes==DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject"))
    {
        checkmark.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        checkmark.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        // checkmark.IsChecked = AllNodes["IsChecked"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("DateTimeObject"))
    {
        DateTime.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        DateTime.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("LocationObject"))
    {
        Location.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        Location.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        Location.Longitude = AllNodes["Longitude"].InnerText;
        Location.Latitude = AllNodes["Latitude"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode==DOC.GetElementsByTagName("SwitchObject"))
    {
        Switch.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        Switch.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        // Switch.IsChecked =AllNodes["IsChecked"].InnerText;
    }
    else if(ParentNode==DOC.GetElementsByTagName("TextViewObject")) 
    {
        TextView.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        TextView.Value = AllNodes["Value"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode ==DOC.GetElementsByTagName("TextFieldObject"))
    {
        TextField.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        TextField.Value = AllNodes["Value"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("PhotoPickerObject"))
    {
        PhotoPicker.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        PhotoPicker.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
    }
    else if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("SpinWheelPickerObject"))
    {
        SpinWheelPicker.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        SpinWheelPicker.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        // SpinWheelPicker.Columns = AllNodes["Columns"].InnerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure you meant to compare `ParentNode` instead of `AllNodes.ChildNodes` with your reference elements?

Comment: i am trying to get all inner value from xml file. not trying to compare.

Comment: What limitations do you have? I.E .Net version, libraries and so on? (Why are you using XmlDocument?)

Comment: @ThomasLindvall: basically my purpose is to create UI at runtime for this purpose i use xmldocument.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\DIGITEL EYE SYSTEM\Desktop\response.xml");
    var allElements = xdoc.Root.Elements();
    foreach (string element in allElements)
    {
        //TODO add logic
    }
```

First we'll load up the xml into a XDocument (needs .Net 3.5),
    nothing odd going on here.

Second we'll select the root node and ALL
    the elements under the root into a IEnumrable. You can add a filter here in the Elements() method.

Third we'll start iterating over the elements in our IEnumerable and implicitly 
        cast them to a string, this is a operator in the LINQ to XML lib
        that    just returns the XElement.Value (so if you think that's more
        readable    or need the whole Element for some other reason write
        that! I.E    XElement element in allElements)

Don't know how to do it in XmlDocument, I've totally forgotten, hopefully this might help you in case you'll go down that path (pun intended).

Comment: to get all XmlElementNodes with XPATH "/*" should work. With a similar approach should work incase you still have the same problem.